# How to know the current file path after being frozen into an executable using cx_Freeze?

Tags: python, executable, cx-freeze

I am making games in Python. Since I am using Python3, I have to cx_Freeze my scripts into executables to let other people who don't have Python3 run the games. I've put the resources (textures, audio, files etc.) in a folder that was related to the script path. When I didn't cx_Freeze the script, I used `__file__` to locate the script and use this to locate the resources and use them. But once frozen using cx_Freeze, this method doesn't work.

My question is, how can find the file path of a script after it is being frozen using cx_Freeze?

I've tried `__file__`, os module and any other modules related to file paths.

```py
path = str(__file__).split("/")
path.remove("My executable name")
path.remove("MacOS")
path = "/".join(path) + "/Resources/"
```

I expected to return my Resources folder, but `__file__` only returns my home directory so this causes a traceback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a section [Using data files](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#using-data-files) in the cx_Freeze documentation dedicated to this question, saying:

> Applications often need data files besides the code, such as icons. Using a [setup script](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html#distutils), you can list data files or directories in the `include_files` option to `build_exe`. They’ll be copied to the build directory alongside the executable. Then to find them, use code like this:
>
> ```py
> def find_data_file(filename):
>     if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
>         # The application is frozen
>         datadir = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
>     else:
>         # The application is not frozen
>         # Change this bit to match where you store your data files:
>         datadir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
>     return os.path.join(datadir, filename)
> ```
>
> An alternative is to embed data in code, for example by using Qt’s resource system.

There is one further point to notice if you are using cx_Freeze version 5.1.0 or 5.1.1: packages will be included into a subdirectory `lib` of the build directory of the frozen application, whereas they are in the main directory of the unfrozen application or in the `site-packages` directory of the Python installation. If you refer to data files located in packages directories from the main application, you need to add this additionnal `lib` to the relative path using e.g. `os.path.join()` (or to remove it in the other direction).

In your case, however, I guess `Resources` is simply a data directory, not a package with Python code. Then you only need to add `'Resources'` to the `include_files` list in the setup script. To get a file named `filename` located in the `Resources` directory, the example code modified like this should do the job:

```py
def find_data_file(filename):
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        # The application is frozen
        datadir = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    else:
        # The application is not frozen
        datadir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    # The following line has been changed to match where you store your data files:
    return os.path.join(datadir, 'Resources', filename)
```